# Spark JavaRDD - function does not return value

Tags: java, function, apache-spark

I have a list of IP stored in JavaRDD as List of Strings **logLine**:
[[54.186.7.47], [178.154.189.203], [10.55.1.29], [115.93.74.252]]

I run the part of the code below to create the new JavaRDD with list of integer - consist of sum of 4 octets for each IP (i.e. 95 for 10.55.1.29).

But when I run ipSplit.collect() I receive [[0], [0], [0], [0]]. What is wrong with my code?  :)

```
JavaRDD<List<Integer>> ipSplit = logLine.map(new Function<List<String>, List<Integer>>() {
       public List<Integer> call(List<String> s) {
            List<Integer> ipNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (String ip : s) {
                List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(ip.split("."));
                int summary = 0;
                for (String octet : temp) {
                    //System.out.println("octet: " + octet);
                    summary = summary + Integer.parseInt(octet);
                }
                ipNumbers.add(summary);
            }
           return ipNumbers; 
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is with this line:

`List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(ip.split("."));`

Since the `split()` method can have regular expression as input, when using the dot (`.`) as input, the method treats this as a regular expression rather than the actual character.

What you need to do is to escape the dot character to tell the method treats the dot as a character.

Replace this line:

`List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(ip.split("."));`

With this line:

`List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(ip.split("\\."));`

Where:

- 1st `\` is escape the following character which is a 2nd `\` because a slash is also a regular expression character
- 2nd `\` meaning escaping the following character which is the `.`
- `.` is the character to be escaped